# Can the gruntjs watch be restarted on grunt.js file change

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch

Can the grunt watch be restarted when ever there is a change in grunt.js file

use case:  I am right now in the process of building my grunt process and keep changing the grunt.js file and I have to restart the grunt.js to see if it works.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It looks like this was implemented in version `0.4.0`. You can see the [issue here](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch/issues/32) which explains that by simply watching the Gruntfile (even without any tasks) the entire contents of the Grunt setup will be reloaded:

```
watch: {
    grunt: { files: ['grunt.js'] }
}
```

Comment: Great! I left this as `grunt.js` because your original question states it uses that name (versus `Gruntfile.js`), but so long as the name is correct it should work.

Comment: this does nothing for me

Comment: i mean.. it does watch it, but the new configurations are not applied to the currently open session. so it's useless.

Comment: @vlrprbttst Hmm, I think you have something else going on then. This does work for me (and reloads config for tasks). Can you put your example in a gist? Might be easier to see what's going on that way.

Comment: it actually works. it doesn't on some tasks (like browsersync for example) but in fact it does work on other tasks. sorry for that

Comment: No worries! Glad you figured that part out.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can achieve it. For example add `Gruntfile.js` to your files array.

```
 watch: {
     js:{
        files:['src/js/**/*.js','Gruntfile.js'],
        tasks: ['jshint','requirejs'],
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This default behaviour is to reload only when the `Gruntfile` changes.

If you want to reload when an other files change you can use the option `reload` :

```
watch: {

        "grunt" : {
            files: ['Gruntfile.js','someotherfiles.json'],
            options: { reload: true }
        }

    },
```

Source  : https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch/pull/285

Comment: This is specially useful when you split the grunt configuration (usually inside Gruntfile.js) into separate files.